# How to get not mapped values using multiple collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> table1

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "name" : "A",
},
{
    "_id" : "234"
    "name" : "B",
}
```

> table2

```
{
    "_id" : "432",
    "language" : "Hindi"
},
{
    "_id" : "345345",
    "language" : "Hindi"
}
```

> table3

```
{
    "_id" : "3498",
    "film" : {
        "kannada" : [
            "200" 
        ],
    }
}
```

> Step 1

I have to take _id from **table1** check with **table2** then take `language` from **table2**

> Step 2

we have to check this `language` mapped to **table3** collection or not ?.

> Expected Output:

```
["100"]
```

Comment: Why 100... why not 100 and 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.UserDetails.aggregate(
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: "UserProducts",
        localField: "UID",
        foreignField: "UID",
        as: "userProduct"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$userProduct" },
    {
        "$project": { "_id" : 0, "userProduct.UPID" : 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            userProductUPIDs: { $addToSet: "$userProduct.UPID" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Groups",
            pipeline: [
                { $unwind: "$members.regularStudent" },
                { $project: { _id: 0, value: "$members.regularStudent" } }
            ],
            as: "UPID"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            UPID: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$UPID",
                    as: "x",
                    in: "$$x.value"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $setDifference: [ "$userProductUPIDs", "$UPID" ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Basically the aim is to get single document with two arrays to perform [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/index.html). You already have the right part (just need to add [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-by-null)) and you need [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to get all the data from `Groups` into one collection. Outputs:

```
{ "_id" : null, "result" : [ "100" ] }
```

EDIT: to run `$lookup` with custom pipeline you need MongoDB 3.6 or newer. Alternatively you have to run two aggregations and then compare both results in your application logic:

```
var queryResult = db.UserDetails.aggregate(
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: "UserProducts",
        localField: "UID",
        foreignField: "UID",
        as: "userProduct"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$userProduct" },
    {
        "$project": { "_id" : 0, "userProduct.UPID" : 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            userProductUPIDs: { $addToSet: "$userProduct.UPID" }
        }
    }
) // returns [ "100", "200" ]

let userProductUPIDs = queryResult.toArray()[0].userProductUPIDs;

db.Groups.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$members.regularStudent"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            UPIDs: { $addToSet: "$members.regularStudent" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            members: {
                $setDifference: [ userProductUPIDs , "$UPIDs" ]
            },
            _id : 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What MongoDB version ?

Comment: @Prasanna you need at least `3.6` since this `$lookup` with custom pipeline is the only way to get the data from other collection with custom condition (by default you have only equality). Can you update your DB ?

Comment: @Prasanna unfortunately I don't see any fallback for `3.4.5`, the only thing that comes to my mind is that you need two database queries. So you can either convince your boss to upgrade the DB or I can show you how to do that using two DB calls

Comment: @Prasanna my code is returning two arrays and you need to calculate the difference between first one and the second one

Comment: @Prasanna answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54130629/6238977  hope it's more clear now