# How to check $setDifference in two array using mongo-query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

UserDetails

```
{
    "_id" : "5c23536f807caa1bec00e79b",
    "UID" : "1",
    "name" : "A",
},
{
    "_id" : "5c23536f807caa1bec00e78b",
    "UID" : "2",
    "name" : "B",
}
```

UserProducts

```
{
    "_id" : "5c23536f807caa1bec00e79c",
    "UPID" : "100",
    "UID" : "1"
},
{
    "_id" : "5c23536f807caa1bec00e79c",
    "UPID" : "200",
    "UID" : "2"
}
```

Groups

```
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "200" // UPID
        ],
    }
}
```

Step 1

I have to take UID from **UserDetails** check with **UserProducts** then take `UPID` from **UserProducts**

Step 2

we have to check this `UPID` mapped to **Groups** collection or not ?.
`members.regularStudent` we are mapped `UPID`

Step 3

Suppose **UPID** not mapped means i want to print the **UPID** from from **UserProducts**

I have tried but couldn't complete this, kindly help me out on this.

> Expected Output:

```
["100"]
```

Note: Expected Output is `["100"]` , because **UserProducts** having UPID `100 & 200` but **Groups** collection mapped only `200`.

My Code

```
db.UserDetails.aggregate(
{
$lookup: {
    from: "UserProducts",
    localField: "UID",
    foreignField: "UID",
    as: "userProduct"
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$userProduct" },
{
    "$project": { "_id" : 0, "userProduct.UPID" : 1 }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        userProductUPIDs: { $addToSet: "$userProduct.UPID" }
    }
}
) // returns [ "100", "200" ]

db.Groups.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$members.regularStudent"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            UPIDs: { $addToSet: "$members.regularStudent" }
        }
    }
]) // returns ["200"]
```

Now i want to check **$setDifference** of both array, so i had added below code but returning error like `$userProductUPIDs is not defined`

```
  db.Groups.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$members.regularStudent"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            UPIDs: { $addToSet: "$members.regularStudent" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            members: {
                $setDifference: [ $userProductUPIDs , "$members" ]
            },
            _id : 0
        }
    }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a follow up to one of my previous answers I will try to fix your code. The bottom line is that you need two queries as you can't upgrade your database so the code should look like below:

```
var queryResult = db.UserDetails.aggregate(
{
$lookup: {
    from: "UserProducts",
    localField: "UID",
    foreignField: "UID",
    as: "userProduct"
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$userProduct" },
{
    "$project": { "_id" : 0, "userProduct.UPID" : 1 }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        userProductUPIDs: { $addToSet: "$userProduct.UPID" }
    }
});

let userProductUPIDs = queryResult.toArray()[0].userProductUPIDs;

db.Groups.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$members.regularStudent"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            UPIDs: { $addToSet: "$members.regularStudent" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            members: {
                $setDifference: [ userProductUPIDs , "$UPIDs" ]
            },
            _id : 0
        }
    }
]) // should return 100
```

Comment: Answer returning null

Comment: @KanagarajSa should be fine now

Comment: No, i used your code, it returning `{
 "members" : null
}`

Comment: @KanagarajSa please make sure that you correctly pass the data between queries, here you can verify the last part: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZZYWsmusAX

Comment: i had copy and pasted your full code and run on my machine, but not working it is working for you ?

Comment: `Groups` aggregation `$setDifference` values i am giving static means it working suppose giving dynamic `queryResult.userProductUPIDs` not working

Comment: First part i am trying print the result using `print(queryResult);` i am getting error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @KanagarajSa now I have a chance to test that as I just got back from work, current version works fine in Mongo shell

Comment: your has little bit problem, suppose grops collection `members.regularStudent` is object means it in not working properly, can you plase update your code

Comment: @KanagarajSa it's always recommended to open a new question since this changes entire sense of this one. BTW: can't you just update objects to be an array as you tried in your today's question. I wanted to answer it but it disappeared for some reason :)

Comment: I had posted new question, kindly [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178838/how-to-setdifference-in-array-object-using-mongo-db)

Comment: @KanagarajSa is there any chance to just update `groups` and have arrays only or you want to keep it like that ?

Comment: I want to keep like this only

Comment: you are getting my question ? can you please update your answer ?

Comment: @KanagarajSa just did that